# Docker nuget connection timeout

Tags: kubernetes, routes, timeout

Trying to utilize official `jetbrains\teamcity-agent` image on Kubernetes. I've managed to run Docker in Docker there but trying to build an ASP.NET Core image with `docker build` command failes on `dotnet restore` with

> The HTTP request to 'GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json' has timed out after 100000ms.

When I connect to the pod itself and try `curl`ing the URL it's super fast. So I assume network is not an issue. Thank for any advice.

#### Update

Trying to run a simple `dotnet restore` step from container worked. But not from inside the `docker build`.

#### Update 2

I've isolated the problem, it has nothing to do with nuget nor TeamCity. Is network related on the Kubernetes host.

Running simple `docker build` with this *Dockerfile*:

```
FROM praqma/network-multitool AS build
RUN route
RUN ping -c 4 google.com
```

produces output:

```
Step 1/3 : FROM praqma/network-multitool AS build
 ---> 3619cb81e582
Step 2/3 : RUN route
 ---> Running in 80bda13a9860
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         172.17.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
Removing intermediate container 80bda13a9860
 ---> d79e864eafaf
Step 3/3 : RUN ping -c 4 google.com
 ---> Running in 76354a92a413
PING google.com (216.58.201.110) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 53ms
```

Pods orchestrated by Kubernetes can access internet normally. I'm using Calico as network layer.

Comment: it's not enough to understand and give you an answer

Comment: Superseded by isolated problem description [Docker in docker routing within Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59899438/docker-in-docker-routing-within-kubernetes)

Comment: Please add more tags `docker` `dotnet` `core-sdk` @Jan Zahradník

Answer (score 22):

I fix this issue by passing argument --disable-parallel to restore command which Disables restoring multiple projects in parallel.

> RUN dotnet restore --disable-parallel

Comment: somehow this solution success in building dotnet core image in jenkins docker

Comment: Thanks! It fixed issue for me as well (local docker build - Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and Docker  20.10.1)

Answer (score 5):

In my case the solution was marked out [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/10275#issuecomment-760963217)

As noted in the comment, "So maybe the issue needs to be fixed by microsoft by changing the default nuget.config inside of mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0."

This was my problem. Docker building from sdk:5.0. Solution seems to be doing the job, which is to add a nuget.config file to the root of the solution.

Contents of nuget.config (again, from posts in that issue):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key='maxHttpRequestsPerSource' value='10' />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4):

i have exactly same behaviour:
i have solution with contains several nuget dependencies
it build without any issue on local machine.
it build without any issue on windows build agent
it build without any issue on docker host machine
but then i try to build it in build agent in docker - i have a lot of message such following:

```
Failed to download package 'System.Threading.4.0.11' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.threading/4.0.11/system.threading.4.0.11.nupkg'.
  The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.threading/4.0.11/system.threading.4.0.11.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms
```

i can ping and curl page from nuget.org normally from docker container.

so i think this is some special case. i found some info about MTU but i'm not tested it.

**UPDATE** initial problem may be connect to k8s - my container work inside k8s cluster based on ubuntu 18.04 with flannel ang k8s v1.16
on my local machine (win based) all works without any issue... but it is strange because i have many services that works in this cluster without any problems! (such harbor, graylog, jaeger etc)

**UPDATE 2** ok, now i can understand anything. 
i try to execute

```
curl https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

and can get file content without any errors

after this i try to run

```
wget https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.threading/4.0.11/system.threading.4.0.11.nupkg
```

and package downloaded successfully

but after i run dotnet restore i still receive errors with timeout

**UPDATE 3**
i try to reproduce problem not in k8s cluster but in docker locally
i run container

```
docker run -it -v d:/project/test:/mnt/proj teamcity-agent-core3.1 bash
```

*teamcity-buildagent-core3.1* - my image based on jetbrains/teamcity-agent which contains .net core 3.1 sdk.

and then execute command inside interactive session:

```
dotnet restore test.sln
```

with failed with following messages:

```
Failed to download package 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.interopservices/4.3.0/system.runtime.interopservices.4.3.0.nupkg'.
   Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
  The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.text.encoding.extensions/4.3.0/system.text.encoding.extensions.4.3.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
    Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
```

Comment: I tried to setup MTU to 1460 at /etc/docker/daemon.json. Still same behavior.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. The mistake I was doing was not specifying the exact dotnet version on the docker image.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk AS build
```

My project targets dotnet 2.2. What I did not know was this was pulling the latest dotnet SDK 3.1. So when the dotnet restore ran, it was timing out.

So this is what I did.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build
```

I had to specify a specific version. I'm not sure if this is relation to your problem but I hope it send you in the right direction. Always be explicit with the image version.

Comment: good one........ i too had not mentioned the docker 2.2 sdk version

Answer (score 0):

I had similar of @NIMROD MAINA and @Anatoly Kryzhanovsky issue when i was using build in docker container from gitlab-runner (docker).

When i run `dotnet restore` outside docker container. Everything it's work!

Comment: For GitLab there is already a long [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/3705) at their tracker which might help you. But is on low priority roadmap.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it didn't work when `nuget.config` was inside the project folder.

I put `nuget.config` in the solution folder (out of the project folder) and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was solution setting docker (Windows) to:

- Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS (true) and
- Use Docker Compose V2 (true)

It's temporary solution, but it works.

Answer (score -1):

Check your DNS settings (A record). Try to type `nslookup yourfeeddomain`. Make sure that IP address is one and resolved.