# dotnet restore comand into Dockerfile always finish with Exception

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, asp.net-core-3.1

In my solution I use a docker.
When I try to build my image, every time I receive error:

Sending build context to Docker daemon  77.32MB

```
Step 1/16 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
 ---> 014a41b1f39a
Step 2/16 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c3eb79db5e63
Step 3/16 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f23ddd06f8f8
Step 4/16 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
 ---> 006ded9ddf29
Step 5/16 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d8016eaadf87
Step 6/16 : COPY ["ProductCatalogApi.csproj", "src/Services/ProductCatalogApi/"]
 ---> 59d2cc3f4102
Step 7/16 : RUN dotnet restore "src/Services/ProductCatalogApi/ProductCatalogApi.csproj"
 ---> Running in 347a48e8ef6f
  Determining projects to restore...

     Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.resources.resourcemanager/index.json'.
      The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
         Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
      Failed to download package 'System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.io.compression.zipfile/4.3.0/system.io.compression.zipfile.4.3.0.nupkg'.
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "src/Services/ProductCatalogApi/ProductCatalogApi.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Dockerfile has a next code:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/Services/ProductCatalogApi/ProductCatalogApi.csproj", "src/Services/ProductCatalogApi/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/Services/ProductCatalogApi/ProductCatalogApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Services/ProductCatalogApi"
RUN dotnet build "ProductCatalogApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ProductCatalogApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProductCatalogApi.dll"]
```

My .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>ShoesOnContainers.Services.ProductCatalogApi</RootNamespace>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerfileContext>..\..\..</DockerfileContext>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.9.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.9.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.5.1" />
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

During all my day I am trying to build my image by other way and every time I receive errors. Help somebody, please........

Comment: Sergey, have you resolved this issue, if yes than please share how you can come out of this big issue? bex I am also facing the same one.

Comment: for netcore 3.1.0 it is still a open issue. Here is the link to issue:
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/9020

Answer (score 4):

You can solve it by using the below line

```
RUN dotnet restore --disable-parallel
```

Also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59752005/docker-nuget-connection-timeout)

Comment: Worked for me. In addition, instead of disabling parallelism at all, setting 5 'maxHttpRequestsPerSource' in NuGet.config improve performances, and still should work.

<configuration>
    <config>
        <add key='maxHttpRequestsPerSource' value='5' />
    </config>
</configuration

(source: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/9020#issuecomment-1035215398)

Comment: Worked for me too. I am on a super slow connection in remote part of Greece and this got it to pass. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, I tried this and it worked.

- Stop all the running containers `docker stop $(docker ps -aq)`
- Delete all the containers `docker rm $(docker ps -aq)` which are stopped by the previous commands.
- Delete all the volumes by using `docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)`
- Better to clean up all old docker images by using `docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)`
- Or you could purge all the data by using Docker Desktop UI.
- Then you could go to the `src` directory and build all the images again using `docker-compose build` and then followed by `docker-compose up`

> !IMPORTANT Please note, the above commands will clean up all the
> docker related instances on that environment. So it's not recommended
> to run these on any production environment or any other environment
> where docker instances of any other applications are running.